# ¿Cómo almacenar datos de registro (name, password) en un Shared Preferences en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, sharedpreferences

Tengo el siguiente problema, de la forma que lo tengo desarrollado me almacena en el fichero de Shared preferences únicamente el nombre y solo una vez, no almacena la contraseña.
Y debe de almacenarlo todas las veces que se añada evitanto la redundancia de datos es decir, no puede haber dos usuarios  que coincidan con nombre y contraseña.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText name;
    private EditText password;
    String userName;
    String pass;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);



    }

    public void lanzarAlta(View view) {
        if(name.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nombre sin introducir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(password.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Contraseña sin introducir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (name.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && password.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nombre y Contraseña sin introducir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            checkAlta();
        }
    }

    private void checkAlta() {
        sp = getSharedPreferences("UserPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        userName = name.getText().toString();
        pass=password.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
        editor.putString("Name",userName);
        editor.putString("Password",pass);
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Intormación Almacenada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Fichero de Shared Preferences (UserPrefs.xml)**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="Password">Andrea</string>
    <string name="Name">Andrea</string>
</map>
```

**En Password, me devuelve el nombre, no estoy aplicando bien la lógica.**
No se muy bien el motivo por el cual no me está dando el valor de contraseña y como hacer que se me guarde cada registro que voy añadiendo ya que solo le almacena el último que añado y borra el anterior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando la misma vista con id `editTextName` para obtener name y password:

```
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
```

Revisa cuál es el ID de la vista donde escribes el password, ya que seguramente no es `editTextName`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jorgesys